# Why is my CSS Flip-Card back-face input getting focus on click?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I've built a simple CSS Flip card; everything works as expected except for one thing, I notice that if I flip the card, there's a zone (about half of the visible input) where the click triggers a focus on the input in the back face of the card.

This causes some issues since autocomplete will fill the back facing inputs, and I can't type in the current input since it doesn't get focus unless I click on the other half of it.

Here's the stackblitz example. It will open up with the card showing the "Log In" face, if you click on "Forgot Password?" the card will flip and show the other face with a single input, you can see here the behavior described above.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8pca9

Also you can see if you inspect with DevTools that half of the input inspects the backfacing control, and the other half the current input:

[image: Inspecting left half of the input]
Notice here the inspector shows the `#username` input

[image]

Here it shows the `#email` input when I hover over the right side of the same input

Comment: Not sure if this is the right solution, but you could add `pointer-events: none` to the div that is hidden.

Comment: @AustinTFrench which controls? I don't see them

Comment: Sorry, I misread the form! (Long day?) It works for me until the validation passes...

Comment: @AustinTFrench It's okay, I mean I can type into the input I need, but in order for it to get focus I have to click it on the right half, if I click the left half of the `#email` input it focuses the `#username` input, can't understand why, and it doesn't happen the other way aroudn

Comment: @marco-a I think that could work yes, but I'm hoping to get some explanation as to why this happens, maybe there's a better fix for it /:

Comment: What about: `<input *ngIf="!isFlipped" type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" name="username"
                  class="wsm-input validate w-100">`

Comment: @AustinTFrench tried it, and actually it now concerns me more lol; the backfacing elements override the input, so now it's like I'm clicking on the label instead of the input, all the elements behind take priority on that zone, don't know why

Comment: I mean on the one hand, cleaning up the DOM could be the right choice, but if you apply it to the card you get some weird animations (as is). It's a small enough sample, I'd probably ngIf one of the parent divs, and set the wsm-input css to use something like `height: 50vh`

Comment: As a heads-up... I tried the `pointer-events` route, but all it does it blocking me from clicking that half of the input, it still doesn't allow me to focus on the visible input... I'll try to work with `ngIf`

Comment: @IvanS95, please check my solution below.

Comment: Check out my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62325280/9060223). It's a clean way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Testing

I tested your code on both Firefox and Chrome. Here are the problems present respectively.

- *Firefox*. In Firefox, the input field on `.card-face__back` works as expected: when you click on the input field, focus is given to the intended field. However, the problem present here is that [`backface-visibility` does not work with Firefox if the element has `preserve-3d` **but** does not have any sort of `transform` applied to it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1201471).
- *Chrome*. In Chrome, the problem is that the input field on `.card-face__back` has a weird interaction. As you've mentioned, clicking on the first half (left side) of the input field causes the input field on **`.card-face__front`** to receive focus. Clicking on the second half (right side) of the input field causes the focus to be given as intended. However, `backface-visibility` works perfectly in Chrome even without `transform` applied to the element.

I am not sure **what exact procedures** each browser runs to achieve the two different results, so I cannot cite any official sources and/or algorithms to show why they run differently. However, I have a logical explanation to why it isn't working on Chrome (the buggy click behaviour).

---

### `backface-visibility`

`backface-visibility` simply hides the item from being seen **visually**. By this logic, there is nothing preventing us from interacting with this element if we can click it (which we can't, because visually, the item isn't there!). Chrome, for some reason, allows us to interact with the element in your specific scenario. Why this is happening exactly, I don't know. Logically speaking, the hidden element shouldn't be able to be clicked, but we can.

---

### Solution

Real-life 3D cards have a front and back. In your current code, the front and back of the card share the same space (in 3D space). In real-life cards, the front and back of cards have a separator (the thickness of the card, e.g. 1mm). We can imitate this behavior by adding `translateZ` to mimic real-life cards 3D space separation.

Adding `translateZ(1px)` to the front and back of the card in your code works. Logically, this is because when you flip the card, the front of the card is located 2px behind the back of the card (which is currently in front). This ensures that the items on the front of the card (which is hidden) can't be interacted with at all (like an element that is absolutely positioned but is located behind something because its `z-index` is set to -1); thus, you can focus on your email input field on `.card-face__back` correctly. The same logic works for when the front of the card is indeed facing the user.

We add `translateZ(1px)` to **both** the front and back of the card and **not** `translateZ(1px)` and `translateZ(-1px)` respectively because the back of the card is rotated by 180 degrees on the Y axis first; thus, we need to inverse the `-1px` value to `1px`. Alternatively, you can apply the `translateZ(1px)` first before `rotateY(180deg)` on the back of the card.

Simply add this CSS to your `.card-face__front` and `.card-face__back`. The solution works for both Firefox and Chrome. Here's the code for you to run: https://angular-krh29n.stackblitz.io.

```
.scene .flip-card .card-face__front {
   transform: translateZ(1px);
 }
.scene .flip-card .card-face__back {
     transform: translateZ(-1px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for all that, definitely an odd behavior but I understand what you explained here; this makes it work as I needed it, also noted just applying a `transform: scale(1)` to the front face also allowed me to click it just fine; but I really wanted to know more about why this happened. Thanks!

Comment: I see. I guess that the buggy behavior is caused by Chrome's implementation of `backface-visibility` without `transform`. In Firefox, this simply causes the `backface-visibility` to not work. In Chrome, it works, but it is a little buggy. This is a mere speculation, though.

Comment: Fair enough, it solves the problem, and shows that there's something not working as it should, hopefully a bug that gets fixed in the future

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this issue for a while until I applied your solution.

Comment: I was having an issue with Safari on mobile. The back of my card has some input fields and the issue was that sometimes when clicking them they would not receive focus. I logged the element receiving the click and saw that sometimes the card container was receiving it, instead of the input itself. This solution fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you can add `*ngIf="!isFlipped"` To your Username input. to hide unnecessary input in the back of your card.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your app component, it will help you.

```
.is-flipped>section:nth-last-child(2) {
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

Explanation :-

When your card is flipped i am setting height and width of div with login controls as 0 by scaling it to 0.

Comment: Wow, this did fix it, though I really don't understand why, thank you!

Comment: @IvanS95 if this fixed it, can you please mark it as answer?

Comment: I will, but can you explain a bit why this is working? Maybe it'll help someone else too

Comment: @IvanS95, do i need to add anything else into explanation?